# App Hub Developer Registration

Tags: windows-phone-7

I decided the past couple of weeks to enter the WinPhone dev world, having already developed apps for the iPhone.

Whereas with Apple, the registration / Payment / Device Registration took all of 30mins, the process on the App Hub is becoming soul destroying, and my shiny new Lumina an expensive decoration.

When I go to the App Hub, top right is "Hi Visitor" with a sign in Link. If I click "Sign In", I get a screen that has my Email Address top right, and the screen is titled "Add Information", asking for birthdate and country. I entered these, and pressed submit. The entries clear, otherwise nothing happens.

Clicking on Profile top right, there are no links to information that have anything to do with App Hub registration.

The App Hub Forums suggest using the Developer Registration program that comes with the SDK - here I get an error, which according to the App Hub tells me I need to create a Developer account. Which I can't, because the sign in doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong? It's extremely frustrating.

Thanks for any help

Richard

EDIT Link to the screen picture:

[link](http://bluefever.net/WinLive.png)

Comment: might want to try with internet explorer if you're not already using that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, same result, press "I accept" and the boxes clear, page stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link and create your [APPHUB](https://users.create.msdn.com/Register) registration and payment process.

Remember you should use either a hotmail or live mail account for this registration

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I enter my email address I get to the same screen. Here is a link to a picture: [link](http://bluefever.net/WinLive.png)

Answer (score 0):

I signed up using the browser on the device, with no problems. you could consider [contacting support](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/feedback) who are very helpful, and responsive - they even have a dedicated contact point for registration issues: apphub@microsoft.com

Comment: I get the same issue when signing in following the support link :) I'll try the email address, thanks